# SQL Cartesian Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying a table of transitions logged and a table of dates.

TABLE A:

```
date
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
```

TABLE B:

```
state | date_logged | requestno_i
  A      2017-01-01      req01
  B      2017-01-03      req01
  C      2017-01-04      req01
```

Expected Result:

```
   date      | state | date_logged | requestno_i
2017-01-01       A      2017-01-01      req01
2017-01-02       A      2017-01-01      req01
2017-01-03       B      2017-01-03      req01
2017-01-04       C      2017-01-04      req01
```

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT 
A.date,
B.state,
B.date_logged,
B.requestno_i
FROM   TABLE_A A CROSS JOIN TABLE_B B
WHERE requestno_i='req01' and A.date>=B.date_logged
```

Comment: how is 2017-01-02 belong to A?

Comment: table A contains a list of dates

Comment: so how is 2017-01-02 related to A or to 2017-01-01? or are you filling in gaps?

Comment: I'm going to _guess_ (you did not explain it in any way) that you are trying to fill in date gaps between 'state'. Please confirm and explain in more detail - it's not clear

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this would be with a `CROSS APPLY` instead of a `CROSS JOIN`. For example:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE ([Date] DATE);
INSERT @TableA ([Date]) VALUES ('2017-01-01'), ('2017-01-02'), ('2017-01-03'), ('2017-01-04');

DECLARE @TableB TABLE ([State] CHAR(1), Date_Logged DATE, RequestNo_i VARCHAR(10));
INSERT @TableB ([State], Date_Logged, RequestNo_i) VALUES ('A', '2017-01-01', 'req01'), ('B', '2017-01-03', 'req01'), ('C', '2017-01-04', 'req01');

SELECT A.[Date], B.[State], B.Date_Logged, B.RequestNo_i
FROM @TableA AS A
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM @TableB
    WHERE Date_Logged <= A.[Date]
    AND RequestNo_i = 'req01'
    ORDER BY Date_Logged DESC
) AS B;
```